# Using tables and column titles in VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm having a very difficult time with transitioning my `VLOOKUP` statement from simply referencing sheets and ranges (which work like a charm), to instead using table and column names.

I'm trying to make the `VLOOKUP` a bit more robust as the sheet where it is pulling from will constantly be changing data, so column numbers will change frequently. Thus, I'd like to just reference a column by its name.

1. I have converted the source data sheet to a table.
2. I have named all columns appropriately and double checked spelling.

---

This VLOOKUP works great (currently):

```
=VLOOKUP(E6,'Costs'!$A$2:$AE$84,19,FALSE)
```

However, what I would like to do is make it look this:

```
=VLOOKUP(E6,tblCosts[Order Number],tblCosts[June 2017], FALSE)
```

I have been fiddling with also trying to use MATCH which is not working either:

```
=VLOOKUP(E31,tblCosts[Order Number],MATCH(F4,tblCosts[June 2017],FALSE),FALSE)
```

---

**UPDATE**

This formula now works but it is returning the order number...not the cost for the month.

```
=VLOOKUP(E31,(tblCosts[Order Number]),(tblCosts[June 2017]),FALSE)
```

Normally I would keep trying this myself...but I am feeling overwhelmed and have been trying for hours. Any advice would be great.

Thank you!!

Comment: How are tblCostData, [Part Number] and [Jun-17] defined in your table?

Comment: @RobAnthony I'm sorry to be frustrating...what do you mean by that? I'm not working in a formal database in Access luckily. This is all in Excel

Comment: Have you defined tblCostData as a Name in the Name Manager? Have you done the same with the other two or are they just the column headings?

Comment: @RobAnthony I was using older names in my "UPDATE" -- I just fixed it so everything is exactly as I have it in my spreadsheet.

I have not defined anything in Name Manager, they are just table headings.
The tables have names though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
=VLOOKUP(E31,tblCosts[#All],COLUMN(tblCosts[Jun-17]),false)
```

The COLUMN(TblCosts[Jun-17]) returns the column number of the field you want.

The VLookup searches the first column of tblCosts[#All] - (all the data in the table) for the data (in E31) and returns the data in the column you want.

This formula will continue to work even if you add columns or rows to the data.

Make sure that any heading which looks like a date in your spreadsheet eg "Jun-17" is stored as Text and not as a Date, as it will not match the string "Jun-17" when you use VLookup.

Comment: Hey, @Robanthony

Thanks a lot for writing something up that should work for me. Unfortunately, it isn't returning anything but a #N/A error.

I went ahead and converted all the "date" fields to text to make sure it could match, and I'm still not getting anything.

In your formula, the second parameter "tblCosts", shouldn't that be tblCosts[Order Number] to specify where to search for the value to the left?

Regardless, thanks so much for your help so far. I'm trying to learn as quick as I can.

Comment: The second parameter (which I have as tblCosts) has to contain all the data you wish to search and return, so just giving the first column is not enough.

Comment: Are you trying to search for a value which is not in the first column of your table?

Comment: I can try and post the data if youd like.

It is set up like this

Order Number | July 2016 | August 2016 | etc.... | June 2017
1                      | $520.00   |                       |          | $34.78

Thus, in my "main" sheet where this VLOOKUP is, I want to "lookup" a cell (that contains the order # entered by the user), to "lookup" the cost for the current month (or ultimately, the month entered by the user).

My issue is that the source data changes frequently -- columns being added / deleted, which is why I want to use column and table names instead of column #s

Comment: I'm sorry for being difficult, I can't format my comment properly. But no, the value does appear in the first column of the table.

Comment: You need to tell Excel the cell range of tblCosts. You do this by selecting all the columns of data and then click on Formulas, Define Name. This uses the Name Manager to give the cells and name you can refer to. Type in tblCosts and click OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150197/discussion-between-tony-kelly-and-rob-anthony).

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(E37,tblCosts[#All],match("Jun-17", tblCosts[#Headers]),FALSE)
```

This match is looking for the column name in all column headers and will return the number of columns to the right of the first column rather than the column number in the sheet. This avoids having to use `COLUMN(tblCosts[Jun-17]) - COLUMN(tblCosts[Order Number]) + 1` when your table doesn't start in column A.

Ref: https://www.excel-university.com/vlookup-hack-4-column-labels/

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this challenge but in my case, the column I wanted to lookup on was not the first column in the table. As such, I had to use INDEX & MATCH instead:

```
=INDEX(tblCosts[June 2017],MATCH(E31,tblCosts[Order Number],FALSE))
```